# Equivalent Ninject code with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, simple-injector

Decided to switch from Ninject to Simple Injector and one problem i'm having here is trying to convert this code into Simple Injectors Equivalent:

```
var resolver = new SomeResolver(container); 

container.Rebind(typeof(IHubConnectionContext<dynamic>))
    .ToMethod(context =>
        resolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>().GetHubContext<PlanHub>().Clients
    ).WhenInjectedInto<PlanHubService>();
```

Comment: There very well may be a way, but I will say that Simple Injector has it's name for a reason and their philosophy is different from that of Ninject. There are many things you can do in Ninject that you simply (no pun intended) cannot do in Simple Injector. You may want to go over your use of Ninject again and see if moving to Simple Injector is something you really want to do. Simple Injector is really good and lightweight if you just need `ISomething` to always be a specific implementation, but as soon as you have `ISomething` and need to switch between multiple implementations it gets hard.

Comment: I must say I never came across a use case that couldn't be handled by Simple Injector. If you go against the SOLID principles however Simple Injector is strict, which is why Simple Injector is the container of my choice. It sounds like you need to replace a registration at runtime, which indeed not supported because it often is a violation of Liskov. Please share more code, why this Rebind is necessary and we can give you some good advice how this good be solved, by Simple Injector or by changing the design of the application.

Comment: @TyCobb: Can you name things that can be done with Ninject but can't with Simple Injector? I'm very curious about your statements.

Comment: @Steven Mainly what I was referring to is the [contextual binding](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding). I don't remember Simple Injector supporting a lot of those things.

Comment: @TyCobb as you can see from my answer, SI actually has support for contextual binding and has so for many years.

Comment: @Steven That doesn't work though when you call `GetInstance<T>` manually (at least it didn't a couple of months ago). It works for constructor injection though. I don't remember being able to do named binding either. I'd love it if I did because I do have several projects using Simple Injector.

Comment: @TyCobb if you post a question about that here on SO or on Github, I'll show you how to do that. Same holds for named registrations. The docs describe how to achieve these things, but when in doubt, just ask.

Comment: @Steven I thought your avatar looked familiar! =)  I came to my logic based on this https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/290 so I researched and deemed asking was fruitless at the time lol. The solution to just check for the null consumer was not necessarily an option as I needed the implementation's generic filled in correctly. If it works now, great. I'll revisit it when I work on that project again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The use of `Rebind` in Ninject is equivalent to using `Register` with [AllowOverridingRegistrations](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#override-existing-registrations) set to `true` in Simple Injector.
- `WhenInjectedInto` in Ninject is equivalent to the use of [RegisterConditional](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#context-based-injection) in Simple Injector.
- The `ToMethod` in Ninject typically equals to using `Register<T>(Func<T>)` in Simple Injector, but in conjunction with `RegisterConditional` you will have to fall back to creating a `Registration` using `Lifestyle.CreateRegistration<T>(Func<T>, Container)`.

You can therefore rewrite your binding to the following Simple Injector code:

```
container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(IHubConnectionContext<dynamic>),
    Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration(
        () => container.GetInstance<IConnectionManager>().GetHubContext<PlanHub>().Clients,
        container),
    WhenInjectedInto<PlanHubService>);
```

Where `WhenInjectedInto<T>` is a custom helper method defined as follows:

```
private static bool WhenInjectedInto<T>(PredicateContext context) =>
    typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(context.Consumer.ImplementationType);
```

Comment: When I tried this, it gave me the following error. "The making of conditional registrations is not supported when AllowOverridingRegistrations is set"

Comment: @KelseyAbreu: Ouch, that is correct. Overriding conditional registrations is not supported, since Simple Injector doesn't know _which_ conditional registration it should replace, since there could be multiple. Please update your question to show and explain why you are overriding an existing registration using `Rebind`. Do you really need to replace an existing registration?

Comment: I decided the best way to approach the switch from ninject to simple injector is just making everything compile first and then start fixing the registration issues. The project i'm working on is littered with tons and tons of overriding due to them registering all interfaces from assemblies.